# Trigonometric identities -- a parallel RLC circuit connected to an AC-supply

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, physics

> An RLC-circuit is connected to an AC-supply as in the figure below.
>
> [image]
>
> $I_{tot}(t)=I_0sin(\omega t+\phi)$ (denoted as $I_{ges} ( t)$ in the picture), $\phi$ is the phase angle between $V_{tot}(t)$ and $I_{tot}(t)$, respectivelly,  the voltage across input terminals and the total current admitted through the circuit.
>
> a) Determine $\phi$.
>
> b) What current $I_\mathrm{L}(t)$(Amplitude and phase) runs through the coil $\mathrm{L}$?
>
> Use the following information: $\mathrm{R}=10 \Omega, ~\mathrm{C}=30\mu F,~\mathrm{L}=10^{-3}H,~I_0=2A,~\omega =300\frac{1}{s}$

I was never good with LC-circuits, which is why I picked out this one out of my textbook.

How do I approach this type of exercise?

I was thinking that since it's an LC-circuit then because of Lenz's law the phase is $\phi =90°$? Is that also the case here? And the resistor $\mathrm{R}$ kind of bugs me in the circuit. Does it have any influence on the current or the phase?

How do I get the amplitude and phase in b)? Although I still think that the phase should be $90°$. But what about the amplitude?

I guess part of the current would flow through $\mathrm{R}$, right? Meaning the 'amplitude' of the current in $\mathrm{L}$ is a little less. But how would I get the value of $I_\mathrm{R}$? I don't have a value for the voltage $V$.

Sorry for my lack of work here. My knowledge on curcuits in general is really slim.

Comment: I think this rather belongs to Electrical Engineering or Physics SE, doesn't it?

Comment: This question should be migrated. This is  Mathematics SE.

Answer (score 2):

Write a single node equation in terms of the impedances of L and C and the resistance R.

$$\frac{V}{R} + \frac{V}{j \omega L} + \frac{V}{\frac{-j}{\omega C}} = I_0 \angle \phi$$

where j is i for math people.  V is a phasor (complex number) like $I_0 \angle \phi$ which represents the amplitude and phase of the voltage across all 3 components which will depend on R,L,C, and $\omega$.  $j \omega L$ is the inductive impedance, and $\frac{-j}{\omega C}$ is the capacitive impedance.  Recall that the angle of a rational expression is the difference in angle between the numerator and the angle of the denominator, and the angle of $R+jX$ is $tan^{-1}(X/R)$.  The magnitude is the magnitude of the numerator divided by the magnitude of the denominator, and the magnitude of $R+jX$ is $\sqrt{R^2 + X^2}$.

The magnitude and phase of the current through L is just

$$I_L = \frac{V}{j \omega L}$$

so the magnitude scales by $\omega L$, the phase shifts by 90 degrees relative to V, and of course it is at the same frequency $\omega$.

Comment: I'm sorry for stupid questions, but I'm not yet fully familiar with impedances, angles between current and voltage, etc.. But how can I get the magnitude of $I_L$ and the angle?

Comment: Divide the magnitude of $V$ by $\omega L$ to get the magnitude of $I_L$, and subtract 90 degrees from the angle of $V$ to get the angle of $I_L$.  Reactances are like resistances for L and C except they're imaginary so they change the angle by 90 degrees in addition to the magnitude.  The reactance of L is $j \omega L$, and for C it is $\frac{-j}{\omega C}$.  Reactances allow you to solve A/C circuits with L and C the same way you solve DC circuits with R by solving linear algebraic equations, except now you have complex numbers.

Comment: Edited several "reactances" to "impedances" as should be in the above comment too.  Reactance X is the imaginary part of the complex impedance Z = R + jX, so it is real with units of ohms.  It's positive for inductors, and negative for capacitors.  The real part of impedance is resistance R which is 0 for ideal inductors and capacitors, so they only have reactance.  Finding V from I is really finding the complex impedance of the parallel RLC which can be done just like parallel resistances only with impedances.

Comment: And from that parallel impedance formula $Z_1Z_2/(Z_1+Z_2)$ you can see that at a particular frequency, the impedance of the parallel combination of L and C will become infinite since the sum of their impedances will be 0 which appears in the denominator.  If the R were not there, the circuit would appear open to that frequency, called the resonant frequency.  If L and C were in series, the circuit would look like a short to that frequency.  This is the principle behind tank circuits for tuning radio stations and for building oscillators.

Answer (score 0):

$$ c\dfrac{di}{dt}+\frac{v}{r}+\frac{1}{l}\int_0^tvdt=I_{t}\\$$or

by derivation we have 
$$c\dfrac{d^2i}{dt^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{dv}{dt}+\frac{1}{l}v=\frac{dI_{t} }{dt}$$ then you can put numbers , and solve diff equation

Comment: A good ,fast reference is :http://www2.ensc.sfu.ca/~glennc/e220/e220l17b.pdf

Comment: I did this differential equation and used the same appraoch as in the link, but I can't seem to find an expression for the amplitude.

Comment: Solving the differential equation is overkill, only the steady state behavior matters, in terms of amplitude and phase. You need to compute the equivalent impedance.

Comment: Note that the imaginary impedances for L and C for the steady state analysis can be understood from the Laplace transform of this differential equation and evaluating for s = j$\omega$ (so it's a Fourier transform) or simply observing the response of L and C to a complex sinusoid $e^{j \omega t + \phi}$.  Once the imaginary impedance terms are in place, we only need to concern ourselves with the $e^{j \phi}$ to get the amplitude and phase of V, and we know that the frequency is $\omega$ since linear operations can't change the frequency (complex sinusoids are eigenfunctions of linear systems).